# How to INSERT rows using UCanAccess?

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans, ucanaccess

I am using Windows 8 64 bit and NetBeans 8.1, Java 8

I know that in Java 8 the jdbc-odbc bridge was removed. I am using ucanaccess but I have one problem

I am trying to read data from MS Access using this code

(1)

```
package javaapplication1;
/**
*
* @author JAY
*/
import java.sql.*;

public class JavaApplication1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Connection cn;
  Statement st;
  ResultSet re;
  try{

    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D://J//DB//database.accdb");
    st = cn.createStatement();
    re=st.executeQuery("select * from db1");
    while(re.next())
    {
       System.out.println(re.getString(1));     
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
}    
}
```

I have already inserted data manually in msaccess 
we got this out

run:

```
a
a
b
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

But when I try to insert data using the following Java code

(2)

```
package javaapplication1;
/**
*
* @author JAY
*/
import java.sql.*;

public class JavaApplication1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Connection cn;
  Statement st;
  ResultSet re;
  try{

    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D://J//DB//database.accdb");
    st = cn.createStatement();
    re=st.executeQuery("insert into db1 values('a','a')");

    System.out.println("inserted")     

    catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
}  
}
```

I got this error:

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.3.1 java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

after 3rd way try

(3)

```
/**
*
* @author JAY
*/
import java.sql.*;

public class JavaApplication1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Connection cn;
  Statement st;
  ResultSet re;
  String ID ="username"; 
  String NAME="password";  


  try{

    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D://J//DB//database.accdb");
    st = cn.createStatement();
    String q ="insert into db1 values('"+ID+"','"+NAME+"'))";
    st.executeQuery(q);

    System.out.println("inserted")     

    catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

}
}
```

I tried many different ways of inserting:

```
String q ="insert into db1 (ID,NAME) values('"+ID+"','"+NAME+"'))";
```

when I comment already passed upper side and try direct values inserted

```
String q ="insert into db1 (ID,NAME) values('a','b'))";
```

but got this error

```
run:
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.3.1 unexpected token: )
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `insert into db1 (ID,NAME) values('a','b'))` is invalid SQL. That should be `insert into db1 (ID,NAME) values('a','b')` - only a single closing `)` at the end

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to use `executeQuery` to perform an INSERT, but `executeQuery` is only for SELECT queries. Try using `executeUpdate` instead.

```java
String q = "INSERT INTO db1 ([ID], [NAME]) VALUES (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement st = cn.prepareStatement (q);
st.setString(1, "a");
st.setString(2, "b");
st.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: what if the ID is auto increment...? how to pass the value into it? @Gord

Comment: @gumuruh - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43323859/2144390