# Insert specific key into Access table with numeric autoincrement (AutoNumber)

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I have a simple Access database. I have a table with this field:

> CodOperazione (PK AutoNumber)
>
> CodiceCliente (testo)
>
> ...
>
> ...

Now I want to inizialize this table with the data from another database.
I have write the code to populate this table.
This is the code:

```
public Boolean insertOperazioneDareAvere(OperazioneCliente op, Boolean trasferimento) {
        try{
            Boolean result=false;
            String query="";
            if(trasferimento){
                query="INSERT INTO OPERAZIONI (COdOperazione,CodiceCliente,"
                        + "DataOperazione,Descrizione,Quantita,Importo,SommaDare,SommaAvere,Periodo,Anno,IDFattura) "
                        + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            }else{
                query="INSERT INTO OPERAZIONI (CodiceCliente,"
                        + "DataOperazione,Descrizione,Quantita,Importo,SommaDare,SommaAvere,Periodo,Anno,IDFattura) "
                        + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            }
            int nColonna=1;

            PreparedStatement stmt = db.prepareStatement(query);
            if(trasferimento)
                stmt.setInt(nColonna++, op.getCodOperazione());
            stmt.setString(nColonna++, op.getCodiceCliente());

            //if(trasferimento){
            Timestamp yyyymmddXmas = 
                    new Timestamp(yyyymmddFormat.parse(op.getDataOperazione()).getTime());
            stmt.setTimestamp(nColonna++, yyyymmddXmas);
            //}else
            //  stmt.setString(nColonna++, op.getDataOperazione());
            if(op.getDescrizione()!=null && !op.getDescrizione().isEmpty() && op.getDescrizione().length()>0)
                stmt.setString(nColonna++, op.getDescrizione());
            else if(op.getDescrizioneRiscossione()!=null && !op.getDescrizioneRiscossione().isEmpty() && op.getDescrizioneRiscossione().length()>0)
                stmt.setString(nColonna++, op.getDescrizioneRiscossione());
            stmt.setInt(nColonna++, op.getQuantita()!=null ? op.getQuantita() : 0);
            stmt.setDouble(nColonna++, op.getImporto()!=null ? op.getImporto() : 0.0);
            stmt.setDouble(nColonna++, op.getSommaDare()!=null ? op.getSommaDare() : 0.0);
            stmt.setDouble(nColonna++, op.getSommaAvere()!=null ? op.getSommaAvere() : 0.0);
            stmt.setString(nColonna++, op.getPeriodo());
            if(op.getAnno()==null){
                stmt.setNull(nColonna++, Types.NULL);
            }else{
                stmt.setInt(nColonna++, op.getAnno());
            }
            if(op.getCodiceFattura()==null){
                stmt.setNull(nColonna++, Types.NULL);
            }else{
                stmt.setInt(nColonna++, op.getCodiceFattura());
            }
            
            int n= stmt.executeUpdate();   // Ottengo il ResultSet dell'esecuzione della query
            if(n>0 && !trasferimento){
                result = true;
                int id= getLastInsertID();
                op.setCodOperazione(id);
            }else{
                System.out.println("codice operazione non inserita "+op.getCodOperazione());
            }
            //
            stmt.close();
            if(op.getCodiceFattura()!=null && op.getCodiceFattura()>0)
                inserisciOperazioniInOpFattura(op);
            return result;
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.logStackTrace(e);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

With this code if

> "op.getCodiceOperazione() = 10"

after the insert in the database the ID is not 10 but (50 for example).

Now how can I insert into a table with autoincrement PK, the specific Number?

Comment: Are you using the UCanAccess JDBC driver? If so, what version?

Comment: I use UCanAccess 2.0.9.3 version

Answer (score 1):

> I use UCanAccess 2.0.9.3 version

UCanAccess 2.0.9.3 – which is over two years old now – uses Jackcess 2.0.8. The ability to insert arbitrary values into an AutoNumber field was added to Jackcess in version 2.1.1, and subsequently to UCanAccess in version 4.0.2. So, you will need to update UCanAccess to a [current version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ucanaccess/files).

Note also that you need to execute the SQL statement

```
DISABLE AUTOINCREMENT ON tablename
```

before inserting your own values into the AutoNumber field. For details, see the blog post [here](http://ucanaccess.blogspot.ca/2017/04/inserting-arbitrary-values-into.html).

Comment: Thomposon, I have download the last version of UCanAccess but if I try to start my code I have this error:
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Table.isAllowAutoNumberInsert()Z

Comment: @bircastri - It sounds like your CLASSPATH / BUILD_PATH still points to the older version of Jackcess.

Comment: Sorry, I have change also Jackess .jar file in my build_path, but now the result is the same, the system insert his primary key